# Asymptotic form of Bessel functions giving a delta

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics, dirac-delta, bessel-functions

Is there an asymptotic form of the Bessel functions of the first kind $J_{\frac{n}{2}}(a |\mathbf{x}|)$ with order $\frac{n}{2}$ and argument $a |\mathbf{x}|$ (where $\mathbf{x}$ is a variable in the $n$-dimensional space and $a>0$ is a constant coefficient) such that in the limit of $a\to \infty$
$$\lim_{a\to \infty}\left(\frac{2\pi\, a}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right)^{\frac{n}{2}} J_{\frac{n}{2}}(a |\mathbf{x}|)=(2\pi)^n\, \delta(\mathbf{x})$$
being $\delta(\mathbf{x})$ an $n$-dimensional delta function?

Comment: I can see that when $a|\mathbf x |$ is small, the LHS is asymptotic to the volume of an $n$-sphere of radius $a$. Why do you expect such a limit?

Comment: Starting from a unique expression, I came up with the LHS result keeping $a$ finite and the RHS result when setting $a=\infty$ from the beginning. I would like now to prove that the two results are actually equal.

Comment: The given identity is a property of the Bessel function itself, independent of which asymptotic expansion we take. It follows from
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \big[ |x| < a \big] e^{i w \cdot x} dx =
\left( \frac {2 \pi a} {|w|} \right)^{\! n/2} J_{n/2}(a |w|),$$
which gives the distributional FT of the $L^1$ function $\big[ |x| < a \big]$. Since the FT of distributions is continuous, it suffices to find the distributional limit of $\big[ |x| < a \big]$.